# non PyQt module stops working after QApplication start

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

In 2014 I have written a PyQt4 app that used a non PyQt module within and it worked as it should for nearly two years. Now, the non PyQt module had stopped working as expected within PyQt application (I have qt4 and qt5 ports, both share the problem). Below is a sample code to illustrate what is going on:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import sys, getopt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication # or PyQt4

# non PyQt module:
import mymodule

# demo of the mymodule use. It returns nested list
# with info about objects saved in fname

fname = "/my/file/name"
res0 = mymodule.getnames(fname)
# res0 = [[...],...,[...]] the way it should
#
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
...
# with or without actual run of the application via
# app.exec_()
...
res2 = mymodule.getnames(fname)
# this time the result is:
# res2 = None
```

Originally, I called the method of mymodule from within PyQt app and it returned the nested list, now it returns None. I have tried to find any explanation or clarification, why the observed behaviour has changed but failed to do so.

I have isolated the code responsible for rendering the mymodule behaviour to the call `QApplication([sys.argv])` and wondered if anyone has an idea what is going on. What bugs me the most is, that the module is functional before the application start, but after that not any more.

Some further details about mymodule:
it is a wrapper of a C library written in mymodule.c and installed via the `python setup.py install` call.

Thank you for any comments in advance!

**[Edit] Further informations about mymodule:**

mymodule.c code snippet

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <extlib.h>
#include <math.h>

...
static PyObject * mymodule_getnames(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
char *filename;

if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s", &filename))
    return NULL;
FILE *fp = extlib_func(filename);
...
PyObject *names = PyList_New(0);
...  
PyList_Append(names, Py_BuildValue("s", title));
...
return names;
}

...

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
Py_SetProgramName(
#if PY_MAJOR_VERSION >= 3
                (wchar_t *)
#endif
                argv[0]);
Py_Initialize();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that `mymodule.getnames` works with two consecutive calls even before the application starts? Would probably help if you could paste the code of the function too.

Comment: Yes, it does. It worked for 2 years without a problem

Comment: it should be either `QApplication(sys.argv)` or `QApplication([one_arg, another_arg])`. Don't pass a list of list of strings to QApplication, just a list of strings.

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo. I have corrected it. Thanks for indicating the error

Comment: @Temmu Risikko: the module function itself is probably irrelevant, since it works before QApplication call. My guess was it messes somehow with execution environment and thus affects the module, but I do not know how. Nonetheless, I will edit the question with further clarification regarding the mymodule

Comment: @LynxLike. Does using `QCoreApplication` make any difference? It's hard to see how `getnames` can return `None` if no error is raised (i.e. from `PyArg_ParseTuple`). Or is there some other way that `NULL` can be returned that you haven't shown?

Comment: @ekhumoro: No, it doesn't make any difference in the test code I posted (in real code I cannot use QCoreApplication, of course). Even worse, the snippet I showed is the only place where NULL can be returned. Everything else is manipulating data read from the file. It's a fairly simple function.

Comment: @LynxLike. Surely *something* must have changed in your setup recently. Have you upgraded qt, python, or pyqt?

Comment: The problem with having a bunch of code hidden as you did is that you can't be sure that the problem code is visible. It is better to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the Python and C code and post that.

Comment: @ekhumoro: yes, my environment has changed. I upgrade qt,python,pyqt,numpy,etc regularly and make a test run with my apps to see if everything still works. It doesn't seem to be an upgrade issue.

Comment: @Schollii: I know MCVE is a must, but here I'm not completely sure how to do that, since the app is part of a scientific bundle with a lot dependencies. It is not feasible to post everything, so I did my best to try and post all relevant code.

Comment: I have resolved the problem, but the question still remains. I am using anaconda to manage my python environment on my main workstation. I have tried to install all necessary components in my system and use that and it worked. It also worked on my home gentoo machine.
So I guess the issue is (somehow) resolved for me, but why is it not working within anaconda is still beyond me.
I will post an answer but not accept it, if someone comes with an explanation of the phenomena. Thank you all for your time and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the problem by not using anaconda as my python package manager. By installing everything in the system it worked as it should again. But the question still remains since the reason why is it not working within anaconda (but did for such a long time) is still beyond me.

I have posted this answer but will not accept it, if someone comes with an explanation of the phenomena. If after some time there will be no other reply I will mark it accepted to unclutter the questions pool.

Thank you all for your time and suggestions.

Comment: Although this is a workaround, it does not answer the original question of why it stopped working, it may well have nothing to do with anaconda itself (rather something might have gotten installed like a dependency of another package) so I recommend leaving it unaccepted. One thing you should probably try is uninstalling anaconda and reinstalling it (if possible the same version you were using last time it worked) and your package.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the suggestions. I think the problem really is on the module side. Mostly the following note in documentation has alerted me to pinpoint the error:

Note: Removing entries from sys.modules or importing compiled modules into multiple interpreters within a process (or following a fork() without an intervening exec()) can create problems for some extension modules. Extension module authors should exercise caution when initializing internal data structures.

Will edit my answer when I end testing the module modifications for further reference if needed.